# Can't add PhysicsBody to SKSpriteNode (game crashes)

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I've just been playing around with some of the features of XCode/Swift and building a simple game. I'm having difficulty adding a physicsBody to an SKSpriteNode.
I've created a 'Bullet' class and a 'Tank' class (which has an array of 10 'Bullets' as one of its properties).

The sprite property is being assigned properly with a texture. However, the physicsBody is coming back as 'nil'.

```
class Tank {
var position = CGPoint()
var speed = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
var sprite = SKSpriteNode()
var viewSize = CGPoint()    // width, height
var bullets: [Bullet] = []
var bulletNumber = 0
let TOTAL_BULLETS = 10

// ***Tank class constructor
init(playerNum: Int, filename: NSString, tankName: NSString) {
    var spaceshipTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Spaceship")
    self.sprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: spaceshipTexture, size: spaceshipTexture.size())
    self.sprite.physicsBody? = SKPhysicsBody(texture: spaceshipTexture, size: spaceshipTexture.size())
    println(self.sprite.physicsBody)
```

}

```
// ****Bullet class 
class Bullet {
var position = CGPoint(x: -50, y: -50)
var speed = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
var sprite = SKSpriteNode()
var viewSize = CGPoint()    // width, height
var isBeingFired = false

init () {
    //self.sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Bullet")
    var spaceshipTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Spaceship")
    self.sprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: spaceshipTexture, size: spaceshipTexture.size())
    self.sprite.xScale = 0.04
    self.sprite.yScale = 0.04
    self.sprite.physicsBody? = SKPhysicsBody(texture: spaceshipTexture, size: spaceshipTexture.size())
    self.sprite.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    println(self.sprite.physicsBody)
}


// *** GameScene
class GameScene: SKScene {
var tank1 = Tank(playerNum: 1, filename: "Spaceship", tankName: "Tank1")
let myLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"Chalkduster")

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    self.addChild(tank1.sprite)

    for i in 0 ..< tank1.TOTAL_BULLETS {
        self.addChild(tank1.bullets[i].sprite)
    }
```

For simplicity sake, I'm using the same image for both the Tank and the Bullet (just different sizes) to create the SKSpriteNode.

I'm not sure if this would help, but I add an instance of the Tank and all 10 of its bullets as a child to the GameScene.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, that you don't add a `SKTexture` to your `SKSpriteNode` but an image. If you want to access an `SKTexture` you need to add it to your node like that:

```
var spaceshipTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Spaceship")

var sprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: spaceshipTexture, size: spaceshipTexture.size())
```

Then you will be able to access the texture of your sprite to create your `SKPhysicsBody`

Comment: That makes sense, however it doesn't explain why I didn't have to add a texture to the 'Tank' class (which I can apply a physicsBody to). Also, when I add the code and println() the physicsBody for the 'Bullet' I get 'nil' returned. I've tried different images but for whatever reason I can add the image and make it visible, but I can't attach a physicsBody.

Comment: You don't need to add a texture that you are able set a physicsbody. You can set a physicsbody to an empty skspritenode. But you tried to access the .texture of your sprite which was nil because not set.

Comment: I appreciate your help Chrisitan, but I must be missing something. I've modified the code above but I'm still unable to add the physicsBody

Comment: Well you didn't change it in your Tank class yet.

Comment: I’ve modified the code above to display the new Tank class. However, now my Tank class’ sprite has ‘nil’ for its physicsBody, whereas before it was actually working?  The texture is being properly assigned for the sprite, however for whatever reason its not creating the physicsBody based on the texture.

Comment: Do you initialize the Tank with your init-method you've created?

Comment: I've added the GameScene class where I initialize my tank object.